# FFMPEG setting audio stream order when copying a stream

Tags: ffmpeg

Curious if anyone can help me here,I have a video file with

> stream 0 video
> Stream 1 DTS-HD audio

What I would like is to create a 2nd eac3 audio, this would be a copy of the DTS-HD track. It would look like this.

> Stream 0 Video
> Stream 1 DTS-HD audio
> Stream 2 EAC3 audio (copy of stream 1)

What I get is

> Stream 0 Video
> Stream 1 EAC3 audio (copy of stream 2)
> Stream 2 DTS-HD audio

it looks good, just wrong order of audio streams

This is the command, can any offer any help.

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a:0 eac3 -ab:a:0 640k -c:a:1 copy -c:s copy "output.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes for sure it makes sense it will not work as the way you expected!

Try to change this:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a:0 eac3 -ab:a:0 640k -c:a:1 copy -c:s copy "output.mp4"
```

To:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a:1 eac3 -ab:a:1 640k -c:a:0 copy -c:s copy "output.mp4"
```

I've tested and it works! Just if you wonder, add `-t 10s  [before..filename]` so you can convert only 10 seconds for testing purposes.

> The reason is even if [it seems] you're doing correctly here `-map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:a`, **here** `-c:a:0 eac3`you were mapping [the new converted] to the 1st position, as instead it should be as `-c:a:1` second position, as you wanted, and for sure the `-c:a:1 copy` original [in second position]to the first as `-c:a:0 copy`.